# Are the Andalites from the the same galaxy as Earth?

Tags: animorphs, andalites

We know that intergalactic travel is possible in the Animorphs universe. As Ax says:

> A massive force of human-Controllers will enable [the Yeerks] to
> effectively **push out into other galaxies.**
>
> <sup>#52 The Sacrifice, p. 4. Emphasis mine.</sup>

Regardless of this, though, I had always assumed that most species from Animorphs were from the Milky Way. Until I read of the Ellimist's first visit to the Andalite homeworld:

> I flew for a long time, longer than I had ever stayed in Zero-space
> before. I emerged finally at a far edge of the galaxy, **billions of
> light-years from the populated core** of old systems and old planets.
>
> <sup>The Ellimist Chronicles, p. 84. Emphasis mine.</sup>

So the Galaxy the Andalites are from is *billions* of light-years wide.

If this is correct, the Andalites cannot be from the Milky Way. The Milky Way is (at the highest current estimates) [160.000 light-years](http://www.space.com/29270-milky-way-size-larger-than-thought.html) in diameter. Thus, the Andalites' galaxy is thousands of times larger than the Milky Way. It is also larger than any galaxy presently known to humans (out of universe.)

But I always thought The Andalites were from the Milky Way. Here are some possibilities:

1. The Andalites are from another galaxy.
2. Applegate didn't know about the size of the Milky Way, and made a mistake.
3. The Milky Way is larger in the Animorphs universe than what (real-world) scientists believe it is.

---

<sup>Perhaps relevant to #2, Applegate [has stated:](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/gzhau/iam_k.a._applegate_author_of_animorphs_and_many_other_books._ama/c1ri297?context=3)</sup>

> <sup>Hah! This is one of my favorite things when someone asks about the
> science. Because here's what you need to bear in mind: between us we
> have one BA in English and one GED. When it comes to science we are
> dumb and dumber.</sup>

---

#### Are the Andalites from the Milky Way?

Comment: That quote makes up for the terrible miscalculation.

Comment: @Axelrod You mean the one about science?

Comment: Yes. It's hilarious.

Comment: @Axelrod Haha, yeah :) Should be a meme like the J. K. Rowling and maths :) Applegate and science :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The Andalite Homeworld (which is never given a name) is in the Milky Way galaxy, 82 light years from earth.

In *The Predator*, the following exchange occurs:

> "Uhoh," I muttered. "I just know I'm not going to like this." "Well,
>   probably not . . . Ax wants to go home," Jake said. "Home?" Rachel
>   repeated. "To the Andalite homeworld," Cassie said. Ax, whose real
>   name is Aximili-Esgarrouth-Isthill, is an Andalite. I stopped walking.
>   The others stopped, too. "Um, excuse me, but isn't the Andalite
>   homeworld kind of far away?" "Ax says it's about eighty-two light
>   years," Jake confirmed.

At only 82 light years away, this not only places the Andalite homeworld in the Milky Way -- it's in the same arm as the Solar System!

[image: Earth location]

Comment: Can we explain the discrepancy between the quote from the Ellimist Chronicles?

Comment: @Fiksdal It could be 1) Bad math, 2) An exaggeration, or 3) compared to a different galaxy.  Given that the Ellimist is from the Milky Way, it's likely the first two.  He is rather emotional at that point.

Comment: Yeah. Either that, or Applegate herself didn't know about Galactic distances.

Comment: @Fiksdal K.A. Applegate is to science as J.K. Rowling is to maths.

Comment: @MikeKellogg LOL :)